# Handlebar.js not refreshing my template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

OK. My HTML looks like below.

```
<div id="json"></div>

<div id="content-placeholder">
  <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#results}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{col_1}}</td>
          <td>{{col_2}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/results}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>                     
</div>
```

And I am populating the above via Handlebar.js and the data is received from the server. Here's the code.

```
$.get(get_data_url, function(data)
{
  $('#json').empty().append(data);
  var rows = eval('(' + data + ')');

  var source   = $("#some-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);                                
  $("#content-placeholder").empty().append(template(rows));
});
```

When the code runs the first time, it looks fine. But when I call the $.get the second time (and so forth), the template is not refreshed with the new data.

I also print out the whole data string in , to make sure that data is being refreshed from the server and it is.

When I check on my Chrome, it tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of null".

Is it something to do with "compile"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time you do this:

```
$("#content-placeholder").empty()...
```

Your `<div>` turns into this:

```
<div id="content-placeholder">
</div>
```

And your template is gone. Move your template:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    ...
</script>
```

to somewhere outside `#content-placeholder`.

Comment: Or you can move this block:
`var source   = $("#some-template").html();`
`var template = Handlebars.compile(source);`
outside of the `$.get()` callback, so you just fetch the template and compile it once, saving resources/speed.

Comment: @GarciaWebDev: Yeah, that's a good point. I usually bury all this inside a simple template manager that deals with compiling and caching on first use. However, I still think it is a good idea to not mix the templates and the content.

Comment: @muistooshort one question here: when u say move the template outside #content- placeholder---where then? I can't make it happen..

Comment: @YoniGeek: Normally you'd put the `<script>` inside the `<head>` with all the other resources (such as JavaScripts and stylesheets). Then you don't have to worry about it getting overwritten as nothing sensible will mess around with `<head>`.